# Specific couchdb views suddenly start timing out

Tags: couchdb

I have three specific views that suddenly started crashing after working smoothly for two years. Other views on the same database are just fine. This is the error in futon:

```
Error: os_process_error
OS process timed out.
```

Couchdb version is 1.2.0.

Here is the crash report logs:

```
[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 18:28:53 GMT] [error] [<0.1434.0>] OS Process Error <0.1331.0> :: {os_process_error,
                                                 "OS process timed out."}
[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 18:28:53 GMT] [error] [emulator] Error in process <0.1434.0> with exit value: {{nocatch,{os_process_error,"OS process timed out."}},[{couch_os_process,prompt,2,[{file,"/usr/src/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_os_process.erl"},{line,57}]},{couch_query_servers,map_doc_raw... 


[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 18:28:53 GMT] [error] [<0.1427.0>] ** Generic server <0.1427.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.1431.0>,
                       {{nocatch,
                            {os_process_error,"OS process timed out."}},
                        [{couch_os_process,prompt,2,
                             [{file,
                                  "/usr/src/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_os_process.erl"},
                              {line,57}]},
                         {couch_query_servers,map_doc_raw,2,
                             [{file,
                                  "/usr/src/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_query_servers.erl"},
                              {line,88}]},
                         {couch_view_updater,'-do_maps/3-fun-0-',3,
                             [{file,
                                  "/usr/src/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_view_updater.erl"},
                              {line,174}]},
                         {couch_view_updater,do_maps,3,
                             [{file,
                                  "/usr/src/build-couchdb/dependencies/couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_view_updater.erl"},
                              {line,169}]}]}}
** When Server state == {group_state,undefined,<<"anypy_suggest">>,
                     {"/usr/src/build-couchdb/build/var/lib/couchdb",
                      <<"anypy_suggest">>,
                      {group,
                       <<179,2,154,154,243,188,196,230,224,228,72,35,138,
                         126,255,36>>,
                       nil,<<"_design/message">>,<<"javascript">>,[],
                       [{view,0,0,0,[],
                         <<"function(doc) {\n\t\n\t// test if messages shoud be emitted\n\tvar emit_all = function(messages) {\n\t\tfor(var i in messages) {\n\t\t\tvar d = messages[i].when.split(\"-\");\n\t\t\tvar day = d[2].split(\"T\");\n\t\t\temit([d[0]+'-'+d[1]+'-'+day[0], messages[i].group, messages[i].who], 1);\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\n\n\t// vacation plan level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'PlanRoute') {\n\n\t\t// route level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\temit_all(doc.messages);\n\n\t\t// destination level messages\n\t\tif(doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\temit_all(doc.destinations[i].messages);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t// service level messages\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\tfor(var ii in doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\temit_all(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages);\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}">>,
                         nil,
                         [{<<"by_date">>,
                           <<"function(keys, values) {\n\treturn sum(values)\n}">>}],
                         []},
                        {view,1,0,0,
                         [<<"sent_by">>],
                         <<"function(doc) {\n\t\n\tvar key;\n\n\t// test if messages shoud be emitted\n\tvar emit_all = function(level, key, doc, messages) {\n\t\tfor(var i in messages) {\n\t\t\tdo_emit(level, key, doc, messages, i);\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\n\tvar do_emit = function(level, key, doc, msgs, idx) {\n\t\tmsg = msgs[idx];\n\t\tvar context = [];\n\t\tfor(i=0; i < idx; i++)\n\t\tcontext.push({who:msgs[i].who, message:msgs[i].message});\n\t\tvar ndoc = {\n\t\tmessage:msg.message,\n\t\twhen:msg.when,\n\t\twho:msg.who,\n\t\tgroup:msg.group,\n\t\tviewed_by:msg.viewed_by,\n\t\tlevel: level,\n\t\tdoc_id: doc._id,\n\t\tdoc_type: doc.doc_type,\n\t\tdoc_title: doc.name,\n\t\tcontext: context,\n\t\t};\n\n\t\tkeys = [msg.who, msg.when];\n\t\temit(keys, ndoc);\n\t};\n\n\t// vacation plan level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'PlanRoute') {\n\t\tkey = doc.staff_id;\n\n\t\t// route level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\temit_all('', key, doc, doc.messages);\n\n\t\t// destination level messages\n\t\tif(doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\tvar level = 'Destination ('+doc.destinations[i].destination_id+') on VP leg #' + doc.destinations[i].leg;\n\t\t\t\t\temit_all(level, key, doc, doc.destinations[i].messages);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t// service level messages\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services && doc.destinations[i].services.length > 0) {\n\t\t\t\t\tfor(var ii in doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tvar level = doc.destinations[i].services[ii].desc;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\temit_all(level, key, doc, doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages, ii);\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}">>,
                         nil,[],[]},
                        {view,2,0,0,
                         [<<"unviewed_by">>],
                         <<"function(doc) {\n\t\n\tvar key;\n\n\t// test if messages shoud be emitted\n\tvar test_and_emit = function(level, group_not, key, doc, messages) {\n\t\tfor(var i in messages) {\n\t\t\tif(messages[i].group != group_not && messages[i].viewed_by.indexOf(key) == -1) {\n\t\t\t\t// key not in the list, emit this message and doc details\n\t\t\t\tdo_emit(level, key, doc, messages, i);\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\n\tvar do_emit = function(level, key, doc, msgs, idx) {\n\t\tmsg = msgs[idx];\n\t\tvar context = [];\n\t\tfor(i=0; i < idx; i++)\n\t\tcontext.push({who:msgs[i].who, message:msgs[i].message});\n\t\tvar ndoc = {\n\t\tmessage:msg.message,\n\t\twhen:msg.when,\n\t\twho:msg.who,\n\t\tgroup:msg.group,\n\t\tviewed_by:msg.viewed_by,\n\t\tlevel: level,\n\t\tdoc_id: doc._id,\n\t\tdoc_type: doc.doc_type,\n\t\tdoc_title: doc.name,\n\t\tcontext: context,\n\t\t};\n\t\temit(key, ndoc);\n\t};\n\n\t// suggest level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'ReserveSuggest') {\n\t\tkey = doc.staff_id;\n\t\t\n\t\t// doc level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\ttest_and_emit('','staff', key, doc, doc.messages);\n\t\n\t\t// suggest level messages\n\t\tif(doc.suggests) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.suggests) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.suggests[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\tvar level = doc.suggests[i].desc;\n\t\t\t\t\ttest_and_emit(level, 'staff', key, doc, doc.suggests[i].messages, ii);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n\n\t// vacation plan level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'PlanRoute') {\n\t\tkey = doc.staff_id;\n\n\t\t// route level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\ttest_and_emit('','staff', key, doc, doc.messages);\n\n\t\t// destination level messages\n\t\tif(doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\tvar level = 'Destination ('+doc.destinations[i].destination_id+') on VP leg #' + doc.destinations[i].leg;\n\t\t\t\t\ttest_and_emit(level, 'staff', key, doc, doc.destinations[i].messages);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t// service level messages\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services && doc.destinations[i].services.length > 0) {\n\t\t\t\t\tfor(var ii in doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tvar level = 'Service (' + doc.destinations[i].services[ii].type + ')';\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttest_and_emit(level, 'staff', key, doc, doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages, ii);\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}">>,
                         nil,[],[]}],
                       {[]},
                       nil,0,0,nil,nil}},
                     {group,
                      <<179,2,154,154,243,188,196,230,224,228,72,35,138,
                        126,255,36>>,
                      <0.1428.0>,<<"_design/message">>,<<"javascript">>,
                      [],
                      [{view,0,503333,0,[],
                        <<"function(doc) {\n\t\n\t// test if messages shoud be emitted\n\tvar emit_all = function(messages) {\n\t\tfor(var i in messages) {\n\t\t\tvar d = messages[i].when.split(\"-\");\n\t\t\tvar day = d[2].split(\"T\");\n\t\t\temit([d[0]+'-'+d[1]+'-'+day[0], messages[i].group, messages[i].who], 1);\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\n\n\t// vacation plan level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'PlanRoute') {\n\n\t\t// route level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\temit_all(doc.messages);\n\n\t\t// destination level messages\n\t\tif(doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\temit_all(doc.destinations[i].messages);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t// service level messages\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\tfor(var ii in doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\temit_all(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages);\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}">>,
                        {btree,<0.1428.0>,
                         {829460268,{128035,[128035]},6593177},
                         #Fun<couch_btree.3.62781489>,
                         #Fun<couch_btree.4.62781489>,
                         #Fun<couch_view.less_json_ids.2>,
                         #Fun<couch_view_group.10.74547581>,snappy},
                        [{<<"by_date">>,
                          <<"function(keys, values) {\n\treturn sum(values)\n}">>}],
                        []},
                       {view,1,503333,0,
                        [<<"sent_by">>],
                        <<"function(doc) {\n\t\n\tvar key;\n\n\t// test if messages shoud be emitted\n\tvar emit_all = function(level, key, doc, messages) {\n\t\tfor(var i in messages) {\n\t\t\tdo_emit(level, key, doc, messages, i);\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\n\tvar do_emit = function(level, key, doc, msgs, idx) {\n\t\tmsg = msgs[idx];\n\t\tvar context = [];\n\t\tfor(i=0; i < idx; i++)\n\t\tcontext.push({who:msgs[i].who, message:msgs[i].message});\n\t\tvar ndoc = {\n\t\tmessage:msg.message,\n\t\twhen:msg.when,\n\t\twho:msg.who,\n\t\tgroup:msg.group,\n\t\tviewed_by:msg.viewed_by,\n\t\tlevel: level,\n\t\tdoc_id: doc._id,\n\t\tdoc_type: doc.doc_type,\n\t\tdoc_title: doc.name,\n\t\tcontext: context,\n\t\t};\n\n\t\tkeys = [msg.who, msg.when];\n\t\temit(keys, ndoc);\n\t};\n\n\t// vacation plan level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'PlanRoute') {\n\t\tkey = doc.staff_id;\n\n\t\t// route level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\temit_all('', key, doc, doc.messages);\n\n\t\t// destination level messages\n\t\tif(doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\tvar level = 'Destination ('+doc.destinations[i].destination_id+') on VP leg #' + doc.destinations[i].leg;\n\t\t\t\t\temit_all(level, key, doc, doc.destinations[i].messages);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t// service level messages\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services && doc.destinations[i].services.length > 0) {\n\t\t\t\t\tfor(var ii in doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tvar level = doc.destinations[i].services[ii].desc;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\temit_all(level, key, doc, doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages, ii);\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}">>,
                        {btree,<0.1428.0>,
                         {829552398,{108630,[]},204390994},
                         #Fun<couch_btree.3.62781489>,
                         #Fun<couch_btree.4.62781489>,
                         #Fun<couch_view.less_json_ids.2>,
                         #Fun<couch_view_group.10.74547581>,snappy},
                        [],[]},
                       {view,2,503333,0,
                        [<<"unviewed_by">>],
                        <<"function(doc) {\n\t\n\tvar key;\n\n\t// test if messages shoud be emitted\n\tvar test_and_emit = function(level, group_not, key, doc, messages) {\n\t\tfor(var i in messages) {\n\t\t\tif(messages[i].group != group_not && messages[i].viewed_by.indexOf(key) == -1) {\n\t\t\t\t// key not in the list, emit this message and doc details\n\t\t\t\tdo_emit(level, key, doc, messages, i);\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\n\tvar do_emit = function(level, key, doc, msgs, idx) {\n\t\tmsg = msgs[idx];\n\t\tvar context = [];\n\t\tfor(i=0; i < idx; i++)\n\t\tcontext.push({who:msgs[i].who, message:msgs[i].message});\n\t\tvar ndoc = {\n\t\tmessage:msg.message,\n\t\twhen:msg.when,\n\t\twho:msg.who,\n\t\tgroup:msg.group,\n\t\tviewed_by:msg.viewed_by,\n\t\tlevel: level,\n\t\tdoc_id: doc._id,\n\t\tdoc_type: doc.doc_type,\n\t\tdoc_title: doc.name,\n\t\tcontext: context,\n\t\t};\n\t\temit(key, ndoc);\n\t};\n\n\t// suggest level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'ReserveSuggest') {\n\t\tkey = doc.staff_id;\n\t\t\n\t\t// doc level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\ttest_and_emit('','staff', key, doc, doc.messages);\n\t\n\t\t// suggest level messages\n\t\tif(doc.suggests) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.suggests) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.suggests[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\tvar level = doc.suggests[i].desc;\n\t\t\t\t\ttest_and_emit(level, 'staff', key, doc, doc.suggests[i].messages, ii);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n\n\t// vacation plan level messages\n\tif(doc.doc_type == 'PlanRoute') {\n\t\tkey = doc.staff_id;\n\n\t\t// route level messages\n\t\tif(doc.messages) \n\t\t\ttest_and_emit('','staff', key, doc, doc.messages);\n\n\t\t// destination level messages\n\t\tif(doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\tfor(var i in doc.destinations) {\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\tvar level = 'Destination ('+doc.destinations[i].destination_id+') on VP leg #' + doc.destinations[i].leg;\n\t\t\t\t\ttest_and_emit(level, 'staff', key, doc, doc.destinations[i].messages);\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t// service level messages\n\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services && doc.destinations[i].services.length > 0) {\n\t\t\t\t\tfor(var ii in doc.destinations[i].services) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\tif(doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tvar level = 'Service (' + doc.destinations[i].services[ii].type + ')';\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttest_and_emit(level, 'staff', key, doc, doc.destinations[i].services[ii].messages, ii);\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}">>,
                        {btree,<0.1428.0>,
                         {829591489,{139,[]},306902},
                         #Fun<couch_btree.3.62781489>,
                         #Fun<couch_btree.4.62781489>,
                         #Fun<couch_view.less_json_ids.2>,
                         #Fun<couch_view_group.10.74547581>,snappy},
                        [],[]}],
                      {[]},
                      {btree,<0.1428.0>,
                       {829452501,[],6016985},
                       #Fun<couch_btree.3.62781489>,
                       #Fun<couch_btree.4.62781489>,
                       #Fun<couch_btree.5.62781489>,nil,snappy},
                      503333,0,nil,nil},
                     <0.1431.0>,nil,false,
                     [{{<0.130.0>,#Ref<0.0.0.41069>},509735}],
                     <0.1430.0>,false}
** Reason for termination == 
** {os_process_error,"OS process timed out."}

[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 18:28:53 GMT] [error] [<0.1427.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                  {<0.1427.0>,crash_report,
                   [[{initial_call,
                      {couch_view_group,init,['Argument__1']}},
                     {pid,<0.1427.0>},
                     {registered_name,[]},
                     {error_info,
                      {exit,
                       {os_process_error,"OS process timed out."},
                       [{gen_server,terminate,6,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,737}]},
                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},
                     {ancestors,[<0.1426.0>]},
                     {messages,[]},
                     {links,[<0.1428.0>,<0.122.0>]},
                     {dictionary,[]},
                     {trap_exit,true},
                     {status,running},
                     {heap_size,2584},
                     {stack_size,24},
                     {reductions,545}],
                    []]}}
[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 18:28:53 GMT] [error] [<0.130.0>] Uncaught server error: {os_process_error,
                                        <<"OS process timed out.">>}
[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 18:28:53 GMT] [error] [<0.1428.0>] ** Generic server <0.1428.0> terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.1427.0>,
                           {os_process_error,"OS process timed out."}}
** When Server state == {file,{file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.2941>,101}},
                          829595830}
** Reason for termination == 
** {os_process_error,"OS process timed out."}

[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 18:28:53 GMT] [error] [<0.1428.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                  {<0.1428.0>,crash_report,
                   [[{initial_call,{couch_file,init,['Argument__1']}},
                     {pid,<0.1428.0>},
                     {registered_name,[]},
                     {error_info,
                      {exit,
                       {os_process_error,"OS process timed out."},
                       [{gen_server,terminate,6,
                         [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,737}]},
                        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},
                     {ancestors,[<0.1427.0>,<0.1426.0>]},
                     {messages,[{'EXIT',<0.1430.0>,shutdown}]},
                     {links,[]},
                     {dictionary,[]},
                     {trap_exit,true},
                     {status,running},
                     {heap_size,377},
                     {stack_size,24},
                     {reductions,1125}],
                    []]}}
```

Also, I am frequently seeing this error in the logs, even though the associated request returns normally:

```
[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 19:20:28 GMT] [info] [<0.3849.0>] checkpointing view update at seq 232409 for xxxx _design/all_types
[Sat, 22 Dec 2012 19:20:28 GMT] [error] [<0.124.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                 {<0.124.0>,crash_report,
                  [[{initial_call,
                     {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                    {pid,<0.124.0>},
                    {registered_name,[]},
                    {error_info,
                     {exit,eaddrinuse,
                      [{gen_server,init_it,6,
                        [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,313}]},
                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                        [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},
                    {ancestors,
                     [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                    {messages,[]},
                    {links,[<0.93.0>]},
                    {dictionary,[]},
                    {trap_exit,true},
                    {status,running},
                    {heap_size,987},
                    {stack_size,24},
                    {reductions,466}],
                   []]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

During view index updation CouchDB runs updates views for specified design document. This also means that timeout error applies for whole this group, not for specific view function. For your case this error means, that your view group now doesn't run as fast as before for some document (single document applies for whole group) - probably, they'd got something big for now.

However, this error is not fatal, it's just a restriction to let query server not run for too long and motivate you to write fast and optimized functions (fast process -> fast response). I see "for" loops in your views - probably it's possible to reduce their complexity for big message list? Anyway, you always may extend OS process timeout by updating CouchDB config:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_config/couchdb/os_process_timeout -d '"35000"'
```

Replace 3500 with your number that you like. This value defines amount of milliseconds that query server may process CouchDB commands (view indexation, design document function execution, validation, filters, etc.) before it will be terminated due to timeout. In response of curl request you'll get your old config value.

**Edit**: replace `query_servers_config/os_process_limit` with `couchdb/os_process_timeout`. This is two different options: first one controls amount of query server processes that may be run for single ddoc language while second one specified actual execution time limit.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution. Something else is the problem, as the error shows up in the logs almost immediately, not after the old 25s or new 55s process limit.

Comment: That's weird. By the way, just had noted second log, `eaddrinuse` error means that there is some other process that used your CouchDB host:port pair. Check with `netstat -l` for other process on 5984 port (if you hadn't tweak the default port) May be this is root of timeout evil?

Comment: I like this answer overall, but it is currently wrong! The setting is `os_process_timeout` (in milliseconds) NOT `os_process_limit` (which controls the size of the worker pool).

Comment: @natevw Not so. [os_process_timeout](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/src/couchdb/couch_external_server.erl#L39) is used for [externals](http://davispj.com/2010/09/26/new-couchdb-externals-api.html) while [os_process_limit](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/src/couchdb/couch_query_servers.erl#L294) is specially for query servers.

Comment: @natevw I'd read code one more time. Sorry for my previous comment, you're right! Thanks!

Comment: The part about optimizing query functions is VERY important!

Comment: I've been able to observe that os_process_limit works as you describe but it seems that the documentation of couchdb is wrong on that one, which misled me.