# CouchDB 1.6.1 on Windows 08 r2 - os_process_error exit status 1

Tags: view, couchdb

I have an installation of couchdb which has been working well for a few weeks now. Today it started to throw an os_process_error exit status 1 when attempting to look at any view. The documents in the DB are very small and the views a quite simple. Total DB size is 20mb, largest document is 2mb, i have noticed that the ERL process pegs the CPU at 99%.

I've looked at:

- [CouchDB delay building index (CouchDB 1.5.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966594/couchdb-delay-building-index-couchdb-1-5-0-on-windows-server-2008-r2)
- [Specific couchdb views suddenly start timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005478/specific-couchdb-views-suddenly-start-timing-out)

I've increased my time out to 50000 seconds, then lowered it to 500 to see if i could find the document which was killing everything but nothing shows up. Stale views still work as well.

Below is the debug error:

```
[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [debug] [<0.118.0>] Successful cookie auth as: "sking"
[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [info] [<0.118.0>] 192.168.247.158 - - GET /_config/native_query_servers/ 200
[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [error] [<0.231.0>] OS Process Error <0.233.0> :: {os_process_error,
                                                   {exit_status,1}}
[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [error] [emulator] Error in process <0.231.0> with exit value: {{nocatch,{os_process_error,{exit_status,1}}},[{couch_os_process,prompt,2,[{file,"c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/couchdb/couch_os_process.erl"},{line,57}]},{couch_query_servers,map_doc_raw,2,[{file,"c:/cygwin/relax... 


[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [debug] [<0.117.0>] Minor error in HTTP request: {os_process_error,
                                                  {exit_status,1}}
[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [debug] [<0.117.0>] Stacktrace: [{couch_mrview_util,get_view,4,
                                  [{file,
                                    "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/COUCH_~3/src/couch_mrview_util.erl"},
                                   {line,49}]},
                                 {couch_mrview,query_view,6,
                                  [{file,
                                    "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/COUCH_~3/src/couch_mrview.erl"},
                                   {line,75}]},
                                 {couch_httpd,etag_maybe,2,
                                  [{file,
                                    "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/couchdb/couch_httpd.erl"},
                                   {line,610}]},
                                 {couch_mrview_http,design_doc_view,5,
                                  [{file,
                                    "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/COUCH_~3/src/couch_mrview_http.erl"},
                                   {line,188}]},
                                 {couch_httpd_db,do_db_req,2,
                                  [{file,
                                    "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/couchdb/couch_httpd_db.erl"},
                                   {line,234}]},
                                 {couch_httpd,handle_request_int,5,
                                  [{file,
                                    "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/couchdb/couch_httpd.erl"},
                                   {line,318}]},
                                 {mochiweb_http,headers,5,
                                  [{file,
                                    "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~2.1/src/mochiweb/mochiweb_http.erl"},
                                   {line,94}]},
                                 {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                  [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]
[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [info] [<0.117.0>] 192.168.247.158 - - GET /tcs/_design/company/_view/Company_Id?limit=101 500
[Mon, 10 Nov 2014 19:22:19 GMT] [error] [<0.117.0>] httpd 500 error response:
 {"error":"os_process_error","reason":"{exit_status,1}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out but I am not sure why it happened. There was a HUGE document 57mb which had been uploaded to the DB but it was not visible in Futon or anywhere else.

I only found it after digging into the debug log further. I could not access the document via a CURL Get. I ended up having to use CURL -X DELETE with the specific revision then a purge to get rid of the document. Soon as the document was deleted everything worked as expected.